# Show videos in Vuetify 3 carousel

Tags: video, vuetify.js, carousel, nuxtjs3

I want to know that can we use video instead of img as items in vuetify3 ?

I tried this but I don't think it would work:

```
<v-carousel hide-delimiters hide-delimiter-background show-arrows="hover" cycle>
   <v-carousel-item src="/img/test1.jpg"></v-carousel-item>
   <v-carousel-item v-bind:height="500" src="/img/testmovie.mp4"></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

These video and img are in my public folder; this carousel shows images, but not the videos.

Answer (score 1):

The VCarouselItem wraps a [v-img](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-img/) in a [v-window-item](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-window-item/) (see [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCarousel/VCarouselItem.tsx#L33)), so it only works with images.

However, you can easily wrap a video element in a similar way and put it into the carousel:

```html
<v-carousel>
  <v-window-item class="v-carousel-item">
    <video controls>
      ...
    </video>
  </v-window-item>
  ...
```

Have a look at the [playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNq9VU1v2zAM/SuGz7W1rTkFXtAN27HAbjvUPSgy0yjTF0Q5Xlfkv49SssVWArTY0t6iR4nvPYak757KT87V2x7KedkE0E7xAIvWFEWzrbhz6Wc6CGsClwb8AdqD3NseQf3FJmglKeMxUhToxce2XIfgcM6Y6ExkDnL1uMFaWM2k5g+AjN53yDorfmC9cQ9tOc4h7Bb8EVg0LCMkLRM1gzSdHVKoEIojkoRcYzkyEB/JDiwxmeCtwkmMomh7L2AK5t6kCeC5CHILFfzkVFfAWpNhbX9JpXhtIDANneRMiHdVIkS2UnYAXw+wJEk5QXh0EKXHq+zcFTZx/jZStZs9o/TMjVOhX+xglOVdEdaZ2obn2dceVq9b6cX3r59vG5YxZ21gR034+kLP1nlx+232nMyUpp50N0vYeGRphEZTkg/QZcZ5bQOoC4zzZdRgb3BN2+zfBB3Lli3ABE0WZUT2e7Rho/1KRxReulAghN4Ry/5IofKqlNpZHyrNXb1Ba2g3P8Vc7SGAbTkvEhIxchnPU+sb7EDJrU9NZZxmN3SN+d4EqaHqrL65rq/rGeskhjFcA+pq6e2A1HQbIroa0cRivoDqcDMxvP+wpzhgleJLjBwnuRkRUuErD6YDT//ACy1lz8a2stCJtci+a82OCq6kid+aSa0Fpjrf/RH5f55TtpjqPjLursoklKj3L8r732PqU/4=)